# C# TextBoxFor input field text clipped at end in IE10

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3, css, internet-explorer-10

I'm using @Html.TextBoxFor() to create textbox input fields in a view in C# MVC 3.  I'm not having any issues with the text displaying in the input fields in Chrome, Firefox or Safari.  But in Internet Explorer 10 when the view loads text into the input fields, sometimes the last character inside the input field is cut in half...   [This is what the issue looks like on my machine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3O2b.jpg)  I'm not really sure what's causing this problem, or how to fix it.  Why would the text in a textbox get clipped like this?  How do I prevent this from happening?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.applicantSSN, new { maxlength = 11 })
```

Edit:  When I go to change the text inside the input field, the last character suddenly appears normal.

Comment: Strange - can you isolate the problem in to something postable.  Perhaps replicate on a very simple page, and get the browser view source, then put that html in a jsfiddle and post here.

Comment: This is not an isolated problem. My textboxes are also clipping text in IE10 and it has something to do with styling input[type="text"] to have a width value.